# CakePHP2のcounterCacheで更新日時もupdateしたいです

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP2.6.4を使い始めたのですが、counterCacheを使ってみたいと考えています。
カウントと同時に更新日時も保存したいのですが、counterCacheのオプションなどありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counterCache`ではカウント値の更新のみが行えます。
また、更新には`updateAll`メソッドを使用しているので、`beforeSave`, `afterSave`などのコールバックも呼ばれません。

子モデル保存時に、親モデルへ子モデルの最終更新時刻を保存したいのであれば、子モデル側の`afterSave`, `afterDelete`で親モデルを呼び出して更新時刻を保存します。

例)

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    $parentId = $this->data['Child']['parent_id'];
    $lastUpdated = $this->field('updated', ['parent_id' => $parentId], ['updated' => 'desc']);
    $this->Parent->save([
        'id' => $parentId,
        'children_last_updated_at' => $lastUpdated
    ], [
        'validate' => false,
        'callbacks' => false,
    ]);
}
```